# How can I remove all POS tags except for 'VBD' and 'VBN' from my CSV file?

Tags: nlp, pos-tagger

I want to remove words tagged with the specific part-of-speech tags `VBD` and `VBN` from my CSV file. But, I'm getting the error *"IndexError: list index out of range"* after entering the following code:

```
for word in POS_tag_text_clean:
    if word[1] !='VBD' and word[1] !='VBN':
        words.append(word[0])
```

My CSV file has 10 reviews of 10 people and the row name is `Comment`.

Here is my full code:

```
df_Comment = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")

def clean(text):
    stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    exclude = set(string.punctuation)
    lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(text)

    text = text.rstrip()
    text = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', text)
    stop_free = " ".join([i for i in text.lower().split() if((i not in stop) and (not i.isdigit()))])
    punc_free = ''.join(ch for ch in stop_free if ch not in exclude)
    normalized = " ".join(lemma.lemmatize(word) for word in punc_free.split())
    return normalized

text_clean = []
for text in df)Comment['Comment']:
    text_clean.append(clean(text).split())
print(text_clean) 

POS_tag_text_clean = [nltk.pos_tag(t) for t in text_clean]
print(POS_tag_text_clean)


words=[]
for word in POS_tag_text_clean:
    if word[1] !='VBD' and word[1] !='VBN':
       words.append(word[0])
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: In the title, the 'NN' and 'JJ' should be changed to 'VBD' and 'VBN'. Sorry.

Comment: Please add where is the error is happening.

Comment: The error( 'IndexError: list index out of range) happens after entering the last code above;   
for word in POS_tag_text_clean:
    if word[1] !='VBD' and word[1] !='VBN':
       words.append(word[0])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit hard to understand your problem without an example and the corresponding outputs, but it might be this:

Assuming that `text` is a string, `text_clean` will be a list of lists of strings, where every string represents a word. After the part-of-speech tagging, `POS_tag_text_clean` will therefore be a list of lists of tuples, each tuple containing a word and its tag.

If I'm right, then your last loop actually loops over items from your dataframe instead of words, as the name of the variable suggests. If an item has only one word (which is not so unlikely, since you filter a lot in `clean()`), your call to `word[1]` will fail with an error similar to the one you report.

Instead, try this code:

```
words = []
for item in POS_tag_text_clean:
   words_in_item = []
   for word in item:
      if word[1] !='VBD' and word[1] !='VBN':
         words_in_item .append(word[0])
   words.append(words_in_item)
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I wanted. Really thanks for your help :)

Comment: Tobias, could you please let me know how to extract  words tagged with the specific part-of-speech tags, such as NN and RBS?